# Interact WITH a running Applescript script/program without leaving the current program (Hotkey, sent keystroke etc)

Tags: applescript

The general question from my specific problem is how to interact WITH a running Applescript without leaving the program you a currently in. Its kind of the opposite question of how to USE Applescript to interact with other programs.

I need to go through a lot of web pages and input information from them into a spreadsheet. I have somewhat automated the process with an Applescript that takes an webpage as input and then opens its relevant links one by one, waiting for a click in a dialog box before proceeding to the next.

If you want to run the script, use http://www.resultat.dk/tennis/challenger-singler/champaign/resultater/ as input to the dialog box

```
--Let the user input the the main webpage
display dialog "Linkzor" default answer ""
set tunering to text returned of result

--get the javascript of the web page
tell application "Safari"

    tell window 1
        open location tunering
    end tell
    delay 5
    set listen to "" as string
    tell front document to set ¬
        startText to {name, do JavaScript "window.document.documentElement.outerHTML"}
end tell
set listen to {}
set teksten to startText as string

--Gets all the relevant link variables of the web page
repeat with i from 1 to 500

    set forekomst to text (nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) + 4) thru (nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) + 11) of teksten
    if nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) = 0 then exit repeat

    set punkt to "http://www.resultat.dk/kamp/" & forekomst & "/#kampreferat"
    set listen to listen & punkt
end repeat

set lengde to count of listen

--opens the links one by one. 
repeat with x from 1 to lengde

    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            set URL of document 1 to item x of listen
        end tell
    end tell

    --THIS IS THE PART I WANT TO INTERACT WITH FROM OUTSIDE THE SCRIPT
    set question to display dialog "forsæt?" buttons {"Ja", "nej"} default button 1
    set answer to button returned of question
    if answer is "nej" then exit repeat

end repeat




on nthOffset(myText, subString, n)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to subString
    -- There will be one more text item than there are instances of the      substring in the string, so:
    if (count myText's text items) > n then
        -- There are at least n instances of the substring in the text.
        -- The first character of the nth instance comes immediately after the last
        -- character of the nth text item.
        set o to (count text from text item 1 to text item n of myText) + 1
    else
        -- There isn't an nth instance of the substring in this text.
        set o to 0
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return o
end nthOffset
```

Now I would like to automate it a bit further so I didn´t have to leave the spreadsheet to click the dialog box when going to the next webpage. Is there a way to force the Applescript proceed without me actually clicking the dialog box? I have tried to save the script as an application ("hent2") and made another script to sent an "enter" keystroke to it while it is running (and then activate the new script through some kind of hotkey):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "hent2" to activate
    key code 36
end tell
```

It does´t do anything.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Either with the "sent keystroke to Applescript" or a more elegant solution?

EDIT:

I go it to work with the "Hitting a button" solution from Jerry below.

But I can´t get the handler solution to work. It clearly communicating with the main script because it tells me it can´t find the list "listen" of urls:

"error "hent3 got an error: The variable listen is not defined." number -2753 from "listen""

I define and assign values to "listen" in the part that is autorun when I save and run the script as a program. But when I call the subroutine from another Applescript it knows nothing about "listen"

Here is my attempt:

```
--Let the user input the the main webpage
display dialog "Linkzor" default answer ""
set tunering to text returned of result

--get the javascript of the web page
tell application "Safari"

    tell window 1
        open location tunering
    end tell
    delay 5
    tell front document to set ¬
        startText to {name, do JavaScript "window.document.documentElement.outerHTML"}
end tell
set listen to {} --HERE I DEFINE THE VARIABLE
set teksten to startText as string

--Gets all the relevant link variables of the web page
repeat with i from 1 to 500

    set forekomst to text (nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) + 4) thru (nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) + 11) of teksten
    if nthOffset(teksten, "g_2_", i) = 0 then exit repeat

    set punkt to "http://www.resultat.dk/kamp/" & forekomst & "/#kampreferat"
    set listen to listen & punkt -HERE I ASSIGN VALUES TO IT
end repeat

set lengde to count of listen
set i to 1

on ContinueOnward()
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            set URL of document 1 to item i of listen --HERE IT ISN`T RECOGNISED
        end tell
    end tell
    set i to i + 1
    if i > lengde then
        display notification "slut"
    end if
end ContinueOnward

on nthOffset(myText, subString, n)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to subString
    -- There will be one more text item than there are instances of the substring in the string, so:
    if (count myText's text items) > n then
        -- There are at least n instances of the substring in the text.
        -- The first character of the nth instance comes immediately after the last
        -- character of the nth text item.
        set o to (count text from text item 1 to text item n of myText) + 1
    else
        -- There isn't an nth instance of the substring in this text.
        set o to 0
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return o
end nthOffset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hitting a button

First, when scripting dialogs, if you want to press a button, use System Event’s `click button`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "hent2"
        tell window 1
            click button "Ja"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This works even if the process being hit is not front-most, so it might be all you need.

## Activating via handler

You can also activate handlers in one AppleScript via a `tell` in another AppleScript. For example, save this as `Test Handler`, as *Application* and *Stay Open After Run*:

```
on ContinueOnward()
    display notification "Continuing Onward"
end ContinueOnward
```

Then, in Script Editor, write the following script:

```
tell application "Test Handler"
    ContinueOnward()
end tell
```

You should see a notification pop up saying “Continuing Onward” when you run that script. In your own script, of course, you could use that handler to move on to the next URL.

In order to maintain variables across different handlers, you will need to use either *properties* or *globals* or some combination. Properties maintain their values across runs of the application; globals only maintain their values across one run of the application. As I read your needs, you will need globals. In every handler that needs access to the global, use:

```
global variablename
```

And you’ll also need to initialize the variable outside of the handler.

For example, this application (Save As Application, Stay Open) will change its notification message, and then quit, after the fourth time:

```
set currentCount to 0

on ContinueOnward()
    global currentCount
    set currentCount to currentCount + 1

    if currentCount < 5 then
        display notification "Continuing with item " & currentCount
    else
        display notification "Quitting"
        quit
    end if
end ContinueOnward
```

In your case, you will want to make `i`, `listen`, and `lengde` be global variables. Put:

```
global i, listen, lengde
```

at the top of your handler, as I did with `currentCount` at the top of the example *ContinueOnward* handler.

Comment: The first suggestion works. It is certainly not the most elegant solution but it was my suggestion to do it that way. I am having problems with the more elegant solution with handlers. I would appreciate it if you would have a look on my edit question.

Comment: D´oh. In Applescript the scope of a variable does´t depend on where it is declared but if it is declare with "global" or not. Everything works now after declaring three variables global. Thank you :)